# C# webbrowser it's black after calling navigate on a PDF

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, pdf

I tried this solution: https://helpx.adobe.com/es/acrobat/using/display-pdf-in-browser.html

If i compile using x86 it works, but it's not an option. I'm forçed to use Any CPU.

```
//Using webBrowser
PDF_name = openFileDialog1.FileName;
webBrowser1.Navigate(PDF_name);
```

After calling navigate the webbrowser look like this:

[image: WebBrowser error]

I don't understand, it's been working for almost a year now and it has stopped this week.

There is a solution or an alternative to this problem?

Comment: Are you using the obsolete WebBrowser control? That uses Internet Explorer and is guaranteed to have problems. Use [WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/get-started/winforms) instead. It's based on Edge Chromium which can render PDF documents by itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Panagiotis Kanavos suggested I installed [WebView2 SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/get-started/winforms) and with this simple code I have it working.

```
await webView21.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(); 
if (webView21 != null && webView21.CoreWebView2 != null)
{
    webView21.CoreWebView2.Navigate(PDF_name);
}
```

If you get an error while executing the first line you will need to install the [WebView2 Runtime](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/)